# My JSON method doesn't work when download app from Testflight

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, testflight

I have JSON method which fetch data. Everything works on emulator even if I load app from Xcode to iPhone, but when I upload app for testing to Testflight it doesn't work (data doesn't appear)  here is my fetch method:

```
private func fetchSchools(){
        let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://somelink.com/json.txt")!
        let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL as URL)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

            let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                print("Everything is fine, file downloaded successfully.")

                do{

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject]
                    if let JSONSchools = json["skoly"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{

                        for school in JSONSchools {

                            if let name = school["nazev"] as? String {

                                if let city = school["mesto"] as? String {

                                    if let id = school["id"] as? String {
                                        self.schools.append(School.init(name: name, city: city, id: id))
                                    }

                                }

                            }
                        }
                        self.fetchFinished = true
                    }

                } catch {
                    print("Error with Json: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
```

Thanks for help

Comment: You are using HTTP. Did you make sure, that you have set the [ATS exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/5435/app-transport-security-ats/19341/load-all-http-content#t=201702260946545609097)?

Comment: This is not the problem. I have allow arbitrary loads set to YES. Maybe I have to set something in Capabilities?

Comment: I solved the problem. It wasn't in JSON method I had to set  Release optimizing level to none.

Comment: It would be nice, if you would add it as answer and accept it, so people see, that this question already has an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It wasn't in JSON method. I had to:

1. Select project in the Project Navigator pane
2. Select project's settings under the "PROJECT" tree
3. Click "Build Settings" tab
4. Search for "Optimization Level"
5. Set release for None [-O0]